# iOS PHPhotoLibrary cannot save video to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I'm trying to save a video file from the application's documents folder to the device's Camera Roll. The error occurs when the *albumChangeRequest* tries to copy the asset to the Camera Roll. It fails to copy the file to the album, and gives back an error message (Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)", The operation couldn't be completed). I previously used a deprecated method (*writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum*) to copy the video, and it also used the same file path, so the problem should not be the file path url.

```
...

PHPhotoLibrary *photoLibrary = [PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary];
NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath isDirectory:NO];
__block NSString* assetURL = nil;

PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:nil];
PHAssetCollection* album = fetchResult.firstObject;

if (album) {
    [photoLibrary performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:filePathURL];
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:album];

        PHObjectPlaceholder *assetChangePlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

        assetURL = [assetChangePlaceHolder localIdentifier];
        [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[assetChangePlaceHolder]];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * error) {
        if ( success ){
            NSString* urlSubStr = [assetURL substringToIndex:36];

            // Handle the result asset id in urlSubStr.
        } else {                
            // Copy failed.
        }
    }];
}

...
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath, isDirectory: false)
var assetURL: String! = nil

let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.smartAlbum, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)

if  let album = fetchResult.firstObject {
    photoLibrary.performChanges({ 

        if  let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL),
            let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album),
            let assetChangePlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset {
                assetURL = assetChangePlaceholder.localIdentifier
                albumChangeRequest.addAssets(assetChangePlaceholder as! NSFastEnumeration)
            }

        }, completionHandler: { (succeed, error) in

            if  succeed {
                let index = assetURL.index(assetURL.startIndex, offsetBy: 36)
                let urlSubStr = assetURL.substring(to: index)
            }
            else {
                // Copy failed
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: any luck ? I am stuck here as well..

Comment: same.. any help ??

Comment: Can you check if your URL ends with extension . mov ?

Comment: Adding ".mov" to the end of my URL solved this problem for me... which is insane.

Comment: When save .mp4 file getting error : 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)'

Comment: adding .mov not worked for me ! any solution yet ?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53079017/1850244. It might be related to push/pull concept.

Comment: Why subset/offset of 36 ?

Comment: @Paul et al, I was willing to try anything at this point. So out of pure desperation, I started saving my remote video locally by just appending `.mov`, regardless of the actual container, and now it's working.  Why in the world would a path extension cause a failure state? is apple really branching execution logic just based on the file name of the local asset?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Anyone have a solution yet?

Comment: @vedrano how to use this  method for save video ? can u give example?

Comment: @ChandanJee there is example on proposed link, so you may copy/paste it.